# why Rails includes ids of nested attributes in forms for update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, updates

So imagine you have a form for `parent` which accepts nested attrs for `child`, so when you update the `parent`, rails among `child_attributes` sends the `child's` id as well, what for?
If I set the `parent's` id in the update action, its not a problem to find the `child` by the foreign_key, is it? What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `children` as well (that's what `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does).
Rails need to know, which of the children you are changing, so it needs the `id`'s of the children.
Otherwise it would have to destroy and rebuild the children every time.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thank you. But what about 'has one' associations then?

Comment: Rails treats them the same. To update the child, Rails uses the `id` of the child record and `fields_for` generated a hidden `id` field for every persistent object. Rails also distinguishes attributs for `new` or `persistent` objects by checking the existence of the `id`. Having an `id` for existing objects simply makes live a lot easier.